# Node.js proper socket closing

Tags: node.js, sockets

In case a client timeouts or I want to close the client connection for another reason I would like to close the socket connection properly. By properly I mean that:

1. The client knows that it shouldn't send any further information
2. The serverside closes the connection completely (because attackers still might send data to the server which we don't want to read)

At first I thought about using socket.destroy() which will ensure that no more I/O activity will happen. When I tried this I noticed that the client does not get informed about this. Most likely because it can't know that the connection has been closed since nothing has been sent to the client, right?

Because of that I thought emitting socket.end() and immediately after that emitting socket.destroy(). This time the client closed properly, but it triggered the socket.end() event twice. **Why is that happening? Is that the proper way of forcing a socketconnection to close or am I missing something?**

**Server code:**

```
sock.on('destroy', function() {
    console.log(sock.remoteAddress + ' has been destroyed');
});

sock.on('end', function() {
    console.log(sock.remoteAddress + ' has been half closed');
});

sock.on('timeout', function() {
    console.log(sock.remoteAddress + " timed out");
    sock.emit('end');
    sock.emit('destroy');
});
```